# HTML permanent Placeholder workaround

Tags: jquery, html

I am using placeholders for input boxes in my application and a jquery workaround for browsers that do not support placeholders. However in most browsers the placeholder disappears when the input is in focus even though it is empty. One workaround is to use a transparent bg on the input field and put a span with the text directly behind the input field and change the bg to opaque once something has been typed in. The problem is that my application now has over 3000 input fields. Is this possible to do this via a jquery plugin in run time? or I am open to a better suggestion. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i wrote and am using:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{
    background-color:#DDD;
}

span.placeholder
{
    background-color:#FFF;
    color:#777;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 9px 0 8px 13px;
    width: 297px;

}
input
{
    border: 1px solid #707A68;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 310px;
    background:transparent;
}

</style>

<body>
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="hello" name="hh"/>
</div>
</body>

<script>
$('input').each(function(){

    var txt = $(this).attr('placeholder');
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    var node = $("<span class='placeholder'>"+txt+"</span>").appendTo($(this).parent());
    $(this).before(node);
    node.css('position','absolute');
    node.css('z-index','-1');
    node.css('display','block');
    $(this).attr('placeholder','');
});
$('input').bind('keyup',function(){
    if($(this).val()=="")
        $(this).css('background','transparent');
    else
        $(this).css('background','#FFF');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have 3000 input fields on the same page? In that case, you need to redesign your application somehow.

If you have a different bunch of inputs on a number of pages and want a plugin to automatically spawn placeholders when needed, there are a number of nice plugins for this. Here is a comprehesive list of polyfills - just look for the "Web Forms : input placeholder" header. https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Most of them dont need to be specifically called for each instance, so you should avoid having to modify 3000 lines of code. :)

Comment: Ugh - sorry. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use value attr instead the logic will be like the below.

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
if(! ('placeholder' in input))
{
    $("input[placeholder]").focus(/* clear value if it is equals placeholder */);
    $("input[placeholder]").blur(/* assign placeholder if it is "" */);
    $("input[placeholder]").each(/* assign placeholder if value equals "" */)
}
```

you can also change the style (or class) of the inputs in focus and blur so it ll look like more placeholder.