# Put fixed text on an input text box

Tags: html, css

How can I put default text in an HTML text input element which the user can't delete (fixed text at the start of the input).

The second thing what I want is that the cursor will be positioned after this fixed text.

Comment: You will need javascript to do this. Also why do you want to do this? Why not add a label in front of the input or the like? I think this approach will confuse users.

Comment: How about `placeholder`?

Comment: @Vucko placeholders get removed when focused and text entered.

Comment: Does the text have to be in the input box?

If not, check the "Prepended and appended inputs" section in Bootstrap's Forms documentation (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms). You can append / prepend text to an input box

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having a permanent value in an input field while still being able to add text to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453215/having-a-permanent-value-in-an-input-field-while-still-being-able-to-add-text-to)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626315/html-permanent-placeholder-workaround

Comment: @limelights what's the point on having a non-removing text in the `input` field ? Then the user will enter some text, he won't see it because of that non-removed text.

Comment: @Vucko beats me, normally I find that it only confuses the user if the input field isn't cleared.

Comment: @Osiris Thanks, that's what I need. BTW, the link for Bootstrap "Prepended and appended inputs" has been changed to: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to fix this with only an input element you can use an inline svg background.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJoBya

To make this work in Internet Explorer you need encodeURIComponent the SVG image
http://pressbin.com/tools/urlencode_urldecode/

```css
input {
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="30"><text x="5" y="19" style="font: bold 16px Arial;">Age:</text></svg>') no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 16px "Arial";
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: A really cool solution. At least in Chrome, even the text size grows when user zooms.

Answer (score 34):

Try this one. It might be helpful for you. It positions the text over the text input using absolute positioning.

```css
.input-box { 
  position: relative; 
}

input { 
  display: block; 
  border: 1px solid #d7d6d6; 
  background: #fff; 
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px; 
  width: 195px; 
}

.unit { 
  position: absolute; 
  display: block; 
  left: 5px; 
  top: 10px; 
  z-index: 9; 
}
```

```html
<div class="input-box">
  <input value="" autofocus="autofocus"/>
  <span class="unit">£</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is already answered, but here is another way to do it.

I tested this code with..

```
Firefox 22
Google Chrome 28
Internet Explorer 10
Safari 5
Opera 15
```

```css
#text_container {
  padding: 1px;
  /*To make sure that the input and the label will not overlap the border, If you remove this line it will not display correctly on Opera 15.0*/
  border: 1px solid activeborder;
  /*Create our fake border :D*/
}

#text_container>label {
  color: activeborder;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  /*Make the label text unselectable*/
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

#text_container>input {
  border: none;
  /*We have our fake border already :D*/
}
```

```html
<span id="text_container">
  <!-- Don't break the following line to avoid any gaps between the label text and the input text -->
  <label>http://www.</label><input type="text" />
     </span>
```

Comment: This no longer works

Answer (score 4):

```js
var requiredText = 'https://';
$('#site').on('input', function() {
  if (String($(this).val()).indexOf(requiredText) == -1) {
    $(this).val(requiredText);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="site" />
```

Comment: only answer that did what I was looking for. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it by using bootstrap :

```
div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">@</div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroupUsername" placeholder="Username">
</div>
```

You can check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_forms_input_group.asp).(check the **username** field)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely position the text over the beginning of the field then add left padding to the field until the cursor lines up to the right position. See example here:
http://www.accessfinancialservices.co.uk/calculators/mortgage-calculator/

Comment: YES THE Text must be in the input, the first part of text in fixxed but the user can add some text just after the fixed Text .

Comment: do that in the backend? or do it with js once the form is submitted.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question in 2013, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Especially now the link is dead

Answer (score -8):

just use placeholder="Name"
for example:

Comment: The placeholder attribute is not fixed, when you type it replaces the placeholder with your typed in text